# Replicate Geodatabase and append to main SDE database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, sql-server, replication

I have my ArcSDE GDB on SQL Server 2005. This we are maintaining at our end at head office.
Now we have installed ArcGIS editor license to regional offices. GIS technicians at regional offices can't edit data in main database at SQL server. thus, we have decided to provide them offline replica of the Arc SDE GDB.

Once they finish their edits, weekly/ monthly basis we will recieve GDB from each regional office.

Question is that, How we will upload their GDB into our main ArcSDE GDB without duplicating data in the server? or how we can upload only the features which are updated by the GIS technicians at regional offices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your choice of terminology is accurate, then you generated a Geodatabase Replica to ship to the regional office. The replica generation process includes a named version which ends up receiving the regional edits once returned.

Importantly, there are [specific requirements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Replicas_in_a_disconnected_environment/003n000000rm000000/) to use the replica in a disconnected state. (Be sure to review the geodatabase replication help topic in detail.)  Specifically, you maychoose to use replicas which are registered to existing data...then GlobalIDs are required in both target GDbs to ensure correct feature registration.

Here's what happens next: the regional office makes the editor changes, then they export replica changes (xml messages) which are transmitted, then synchronized back at the main office GDb...these changes should end up in the version which originated the replica. Once the XML replica synchronization changes are processed into the source replica version, normal GDb reconcile/verification/post processing can occur. (Please also review the GDb Replica [Synchronization help section](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_synchronization/003n000000r9000000/) here.)

Note that, just as you asked, only the regional office edits are transmitted and scnced back to the base which makes the network throughputmore efficient.  There are web-based methods and APIs to move the replica data back and forth efficiently.

I have frequent success practicing the basic replication above in a single GDb instance with differing Owners...thats similar to working between base and regional GDbs but skips thenetwork bandwidth. Also, there are tools in ESRIs forum notes to review the replica XML if diagnostics are needed.

Comment: Dear Jason, i am not able to create check-out replica itself. it is giving message of "Replica creation failed. no items found".

Comment: this ESRI help topic (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Preparing_data_for_replication/003n000000z5000000/) clarifies the GDb steps that enable replication...most problems come from taking short-cuts to get the steps done quickly. Take your time and make sure the Create Replica wizard is filled in completely with meaningful user input.     Your specific error suggests that either you did not select any data to replicate, or that you may not have correct permissions to generate versions/replicas.  A)Are your GDb featureclasses versioned? B)What EDIT privs are assigned?

Comment: Thanks Jason, now i have created separate mxd file for replication and it;s working fine. if the field crew update some attributes in the replicated GDB and when i synchronize the GDB, once update completes, How this synchronization will happen ? will it append only updated entities in master GDB or it will duplicate all the entities from replicated GDB to Master GDB?